# Rackspace cloud file c#, adding files to directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, filepath, rackspace-cloud

Adding files to a specific directory using rackspace cloud files, c# bindings api more specifically reference: https://github.com/rackspace/csharp-cloudfiles

For some strange reason doing something like:

```
    public static void UploadFile(CSImageDTO file)
    {
        var connection = new Connection(UserCredentials);
        var containerItemList = connection.GetContainerItemList(ContainerName);

        if (!containerItemList.Contains(file.Filename))
            connection.PutStorageItem(ContainerName, file.File, Path.Combine(MyPath, Path.GetFileName(file.Filename)));
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException("we dont know what to do now...");
    }
```

Presuming MyPath = "Funky";

This adds files like so:

- Funky/Image1.jpg
- Funky/Image5.png
- ...

I could get the file path using `Path.GetFileName(filepath)` and return that to the view, but I want to know my files are not stored under the directory "Funky", instead the actual file name is called `"Funky/Image1.png"`? or so it appears using my code:

```
 public static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles()
        {
            var connection = new Connection(UserCredentials);

            var parameters = new Dictionary<GetItemListParameters, string>();
            //parameters.Add(GetItemListParameters.Path, MyPath);

            var containerItemList = connection.GetContainerItemList(ContainerName, parameters)
                .Where(x => Path.HasExtension(x));
            //.Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x));

            return containerItemList;
        }
```

Also note: I have to use this filter to make sure I dont get the file folder back...

```
.Where(x => Path.HasExtension(x));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a Flat file system...